# Hypothesis testing for quantiles

Tags: hypothesis-testing, quantiles

Suppose we want to test $H_0: q_\tau=q$ vs. $H_a: q_\tau>q$, where $q_\tau$ is the quantile of order $\tau$ of a certain population.

A popular test for this hypothesis is the sign test, which rejects $H_0$ iff $X_{(m)}>q$, where $X_{(j)}$ is the $j$-th order statistic of a sample from the population and $m\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$ determines the significance level.

A different possibility would be to reject $H_0$ iff $X_{([n\tau]+1)}>p$, where $p$ is calibrated to obtain a desired significance level (in this case we cannot obtain the desired $p$ without knowing the population distribution, but it can be approximated using the CLT for quantiles).

My question is: why is the sign test more popular than the second option? Are there studies comparing their power?